# Applications of words?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

What are some real-life applications of (Sturmian) words? I'm doing an undergraduate thesis on the Fibonacci infinite word $f$, and although what I'm doing is purely theoretical (by counting maximal occurrences of factors of $f$), I want to put in the introduction a one- or two-sentence application of words. But I can't seem to find one online. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume you've checked already https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_word#Applications (though it does not say a lot, quasicrystals are quite important in contemporary physics)

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote the introduction of J. Berstel, [Sturmian and Episturmian Words. A Survey of Some Recent Results](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~berstel/Articles/2007SturmianThessalonique.pdf),
Algebraic Informatics LNCS 4728, pp 23-47 (2007)

> Sturmian words have a geometric description as digitized straight lines.
>   Computer representation of lines has been an active subject
>   of research, although early theory of Sturmian words remained
>   unnoticed in the patter recognition community. The paper [1] is a
>   review of recognition of straight lines with respect to interaction
>   with other disciplines.

[1] Klette, R., Rosenfeld, A.: [Digital Straightness—a review](http://www.citr.auckland.ac.nz/techreports/2001/CITR-TR-93.pdf) Discrete Appl. Math. 139, 197–230 (2004)